# Null return error ( null pointer exception)

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I have been trying out coding some views, event handlers and also the shared preference class. In the code below, I get the following error:

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference"

I have checked my code many times but I can't find the code where I am calling a null object. Please help.

Main class:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView displayText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        if(storedUsername == null){
            storedUsername = pref.getString("username", "empty");

        }
        if (storedPassword == null){
            storedPassword = pref.getString("password", "empty");
        }

        displayText.setText(storedUsername + " " + storedPassword);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();




    }
}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.czolb.persistence.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what is 'username' inside onClick method?

Comment: EditText username u have declared it locally hw can u access in onClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onClick(View view)` method doesn't have access to your `onCreate()` methods variables you've declared:

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Take them out of method and declare inside your class.

Simply your code should look like this:

```
--YourClassName-- {

    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView displayText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        if(storedUsername == null){
            storedUsername = pref.getString("username", "empty");
        }

        if (storedPassword == null){
            storedPassword = pref.getString("password", "empty");
        }

        displayText.setText(storedUsername + " " + storedPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the code. Why shouldn't it compile? There are instance variables and local variables, all he has to do is to take the local variables out of the onCreate method and make them instance variables.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please make sure to upvote it and mark as a 'correct answer'